# jquery change event modify two different id and values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have that code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#m_pair').on('change', function() {              
    if ($(this).val() == 'pair'){ 
        $ilosc_pair = $('#quantity_wanted').val();
        $ilosc_pair = $ilosc_pair * 2;
        $("#quantity_wanted").val($ilosc_pair).change();
        $("#group_5").val("35").change();   
    } else if ($(this).val() == 'single'){ 
        $("#group_5").val("34").change(); 
    }
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I code change only one id: `quantity_wanted` or `group_5`. I can't modify two elements in that single event - only one. 
For a second I see on web page that `quantity_wanted` change value (multiply *2), but after a second back to previous value. 
If I cut the line:

```
`$("#quantity_wanted").val($ilosc_pair).change();`
```

or

```
`$("#group_5").val("35").change();`
```

the code work as it should, both they don't want to work.

Event start when one html drop-down list change, and should change one text field and one (another) drop down list.

EDIT:

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
   <label for="Heading">Heading</label>
   <select name="m_heading" id="m_heading">
      <option value="pencil_pleat" selected="selected">pencil pleat</option>
      <option value="tab_tops">tab tops</option>
      <option value="gathered">gathered </option>
   </select>
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">
   <label for="Type">Type</label>
   <select name="m_pair" id="m_pair">
      <option value="single" selected="1">single</option>
      <option value="pair">pair</option>
   </select>
</form>
<form method="post" action="{$customizationFormTarget}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="customizationForm" class="clearfix">
   <p class="infoCustomizable">
      {l s='After saving your customized product, remember to add it to your cart.'}
   </p>
   {if $product->text_fields|intval}
   <div class="customizableProductsText">
      <h3>{l s='Please enter dimensions for price calculations:'}</h3>
      <ul id="text_fields">
         {counter start=0 assign='customizationField'}
         {foreach from=$customizationFields item='field' name='customizationFields'}
         {if $field.type == 1}
         <li class="customizationUploadLine{if $field.required} required{/if}">
            <label for ="textField{$customizationField}">{assign var='key' value='textFields_'|cat:$product->id|cat:'_'|cat:$field.id_customization_field} {if !empty($field.name)}{$field.name}{/if}{if $field.required}<sup>*</sup>{/if}</label>
            <textarea name="textField{$field.id_customization_field}" id="textField{$customizationField}" rows="1" cols="40" class="customization_block_input">{if isset($textFields.$key)}{$textFields.$key|stripslashes}{/if}</textarea>
         </li>
         {counter}
         {/if}
         {/foreach}
      </ul>
   </div>
   {/if}
   <p id="customizedDatas">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantityBackup" id="quantityBackup" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="submitCustomizedDatas" value="1" />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="{l s='Save'}" onclick="javascript:saveCustomization()" />
      <span id="ajax-loader" style="display:none"><img src="{$img_ps_dir}loader.gif" alt="loader" /></span>
   </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#m_heading').on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == 'pencil_pleat'){ $("#group_1").val("1").change(); }
   else if ($(this).val() == 'tab_tops'){ $("#group_1").val("2").change(); }
   else if ($(this).val() == 'gathered'){ $("#group_1").val("3").change(); }
   });

</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#m_pair').on('change', function() {               
   if ($(this).val() == 'pair'){ 
   $ilosc_pair = $('#quantity_wanted').val();
   $ilosc_pair = $ilosc_pair * 2;
   $("#quantity_wanted").val($ilosc_pair).change();
   $("#group_5").val("35").change();   
   //           alert("Your quantity has been doubled and your order marked as pair");
   }
   else if ($(this).val() == 'single'){ $("#group_5").val("34").change(); }
   });

</script>
```

EDIT:

@John S Yeah, there is a problem. I don't found it for now, but somewhere there is another evend handler who change value back to the same. I just don't get it why if I use one .change() it is overwriten, and while I use 2x .change() not. Anyway thank you guys for help and track me to right direction :)

Comment: Why do you use `.change()`?

Comment: One of the elements is a Drop-down list, and don't whant change without .change()

Comment: One should never have duplicate ID in single HTML.. Invalid markup...

Comment: You can hit multiple elements by using DOM wildcards; `*[id^="group_"]`. Or however you would want to use it.

Comment: You should fiddle this. I don't quite understand the desired logic behind.

Comment: Is this is what you want to achieve: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEpky/) ?

Comment: Exactly - on Fiddle it works, on web page i have issues as i mentioned.

Comment: give us the rest of your code (HTML and JS) so we can see what might be conflicting there

Comment: Agree with @Deryck post your HTML here, maybe there are some errors

Comment: It's Prestashop modification, so post whole code will be impossible but i will try.

Comment: Even with all the code you posted, you still don't show any "change" event handlers for the elements with ids "quantity_wanted" and "group_5". You call `.change()` on those elements, so do they have event handlers defined somewhere?

Comment: Maybe just some workaround how to use one one change event two lines? $("#id").val("").change();

Comment: John S: PHP functions create "quantity_wanted" and "group_5" elements. (text field and drop box). Id are ok, since if i cut one change event code works. It's CMS, so there are +5k files. Anyway, you said that that code should work's and there is name conflict?

Comment: I'm sure the ids are fine, but the problem may be in the change handlers for those elements.

Comment: @John S Yeah, there is a problem. I don't found it for now, but somewhere there is another evend handler who change value back to the same. I just don't get it why if i use one .change() he is overwriten, and while i use 2x .change() not. Anyway thank you guys for help and track me to right direction :)